# Number of ways of assigning n people to 2 different trips

Tags: combinatorics

Residents of village $X$ can sing up for 2 one day trips, one to canyon $A$ and second to waterfall $W$. Each trip is happening on only one of two different Saturdays (if W is on one Saturday, then A is on second and vice versa). How many ways are there of creating these trips if village X has $n$ residents? Let's say that residents aren't obligated to sing up for any of these trips.

My take on that:

- $S_1$ - One of Saturdays,
- $S_2$ - Second of Saturdays

There are 2 combinations of these trips:

- $S_1W$ + $S_2A$
- $S_1A$ + $S_2W$

Then, every resident of $X$ can choose between these 2 combinations, thus we have $2 \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$ ways of creating trips.

I thought this is correct reasoning, but I'm not completely sure.

Thanks

Comment: Why the factor 2 in front of $2^n$?

Comment: It isn't clear what the options are.  Must a resident sign up for both?  Is it possible to do just one or neither?  If it has to be both, then the answer is just $2^n$ as the selection is determined by a single choice.

Comment: If you mean those $n$ residents are the ones who are signing up, then yes, you are correct. $2^n$ ways to assign residents to trips, two ways to assign trips to Saturdays.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  The phrasing is very vague.  "These trips are happening on two different Saturdays"  is hardly equivalent to "Each trip is happening on each of two different Saturdays" which is how you seem to interpret it.  Perhaps $A$ happens just on the first Saturday and $W$ happens only on the second.  That seems consistent with the phrasing.  And then residents can go to neither, both, just $A$, or just $W$...so $4^n$.  Vague questions lead to multiple answers.  Can you narrow them down for us?

Comment: @lulu I edited my post. I hope it's more clear now. Sorry for my english, I think I wrote this post in too much hurry.

Comment: No problem.  But then I think my reading turns out to be correct, no?  A resident has four options:  Both, Just $A$, Just $W$, Neither.  So $4^n$.

Comment: Well, yeah, I think you're right. After clarifying some details, the task content has become more clear. Thanks.